# How to include menu options with custom icons?

Tags: unicode, react-native, react-native-popup-menu

The documentation for react native popup menu mentions how to create menu options with a checkmark

const CheckedOption = (props) => (
  
)

I want to create menu options with custom icons.  I do not have the unicode value for those icons.  I created a custom MenuOptionWithIcon component and wrapped the icon and the menu option inside a view.

```
export class MenuOptionWithIcon
    extends React.Component<IMenuOptionProps, {}> {

    public static defaultProps: Partial<IMenuOptionProps> = {
        disabled: false,
    };

    public render() {
        return (
            <View style={PopupMenuStyleSheet.menuOptionWithIcon}>
                {this.props.icon}
                <MenuOption
                    {...this.props}
                    text={this.props.text}
                    onSelect={this.props.onSelect}
                    disabled={this.props.disabled}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But I am not able to apply customStyles to these options now.  I want to increase the padding of each of these options so that the tap target is increased.  Is this the right way to create a custom menu option with an icon?  Or is there a way to get unicode values for the icons that I need?  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Based on the suggestion in the answer below, I did the following but I now only see the text in my menu option.  I don't see the Icon being displayed.  onSelect works, text is displayed but the icon is not displayed.

```
const IconOption = (props) => (
  <MenuOption {...props}>
     <Icon name={props.iconName} size={30} />
     {props.children}
  </MenuOption>
);

<MenuOptions customStyles={MenuOptionStyles}>
   <IconOption
       iconName='md-bookmark'
       onSelect={this.onSelectSave.bind(this)}
       text={MenuOptionStrings.Save}
   />
</MenuOptions>
```

Comment: Actually I found unicodes for the icons that I am looking for here http://fontello.github.io/entypo/demo.html.  But when I include these along with text, I get some random images.  Could it mean that some fonts are not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the icons you need special font - use e.g. `react-native-vector-icons` and then use the same approach as for CheckedOption:

```
const IconOption = ({iconName, text, ...others}) => (
  <MenuOption {...others} >
    <Text>
      <Icon name={iconName} />
      {' ' + text}
    </Text>
  </MenuOption>
)
```

Comment: I declared IconOption the same way as in your answer and included it inside MenuOptions.  <MenuOptions> <IconOption iconName='bookmark' text='Bookmark' onSelect={this.onSelectBookmark.bind(this)} /> </MenuOptions>.  But I get a compile error - JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I fixed that issue, it was a bracket issue.  I have edited the original question with what I am seeing with your answer.  @sodik Please let me know how to handle this!